# Want to extract out only alpha using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to extract **alpha** channel from the video using `ffmpeg` in which *black* will mean *transparent* and *white* will mean *opaque*

I used this:

- http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/quot-Extracting-quot-Alpha-Channel-td3700227.html

But video output was a black screen. The command I used was :

```
ffmpeg -i 5.mov -vf "[0:v] format=rgba, split [T1], fifo, lutrgb=r=minval:g=minval:b=minval, [T2] overlay [out]; [T1] fifo, lutrgb=r=maxval:g=maxval:b=maxval [T2]"   out.mov
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead,

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf alphaextract,format=yuv420p output.mov
```

Comment: Getting this error while executing this command [Parsed_alphaextract_0 @ 0x97cc60] Requested planes not available.
[Parsed_alphaextract_0 @ 0x97cc60] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_alphaextract_0
Error opening filters!

Comment: Yes, the source has to contain an alpha plane. Looks like your input doesn't have one.

Comment: Yes just checked with a different video works nicely thanks