# Use ffmpeg to render out only single Y-channel - either alpha or grayscale

Tags: ffmpeg, grayscale

I'd like to have a ffmpeg command to save only the alpha-channel. All the commands I tried will save a single channel as RGB - with the same values in all 3 channels.
Some reference -
[Want to extract out only alpha using ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/1092015/want-to-extract-out-only-alpha-using-ffmpeg)

From my experience, saving only the Y-channel is not possible. This can be used to save single-channel grayscale or alpha-only information.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [extractplanes](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#extractplanes) filter.

[image: original image]
[image: y plane]
<sub>Original image and extracted Y channel.</sub>

Extract Y color channel component:

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -filter_complex "extractplanes=y" y.jpg
```

Extract Y+U+V:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "extractplanes=y+u+v[y][u][v]" -map "[y]" y.mp4 -map "[u]" u.mp4 -map "[v]" v.mp4
```

Available values:

- `y`
- `u`
- `v`
- `a`
- `r`
- `g`
- `b`

Choosing planes not available in the input will result in the error `Requested planes not available`. That means you cannot select RGB planes from a YUV input and vice-versa.

Comment: If I supply a single rawvideo -pix_fmt gray frame - how would the final command be ? I think x264 cannot compress single channel, it will always use yuv - but I think mjpeg can accept a single channel for compression.

Comment: I can change the input to a single channel. I am interested in a codec that will only save a single channel. Even if you supply a grayscale to x264 it will save the  chroma channels. I think its the same for mjpeg - I wish to save only 1 channel. Thats a different problem from extracting grayscale.

Comment: @AnmolMishra Use an encoder that supports gray, such as tiff, or output rawvideo: `ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex extractplanes=y y.yuv`. See `ffmpeg -encoders` and `ffmpeg -h encoder=<encoder name>`.

Comment: In your answer - ***ffmpeg -i input.jpg -filter_complex "extractplanes=y" y.jpg*** does y.jpg have only a single Y-channel ?

Comment: @moi No. The ffmpeg JPEG encoder (named *mjpeg*) supports yuvj420p yuvj422p yuvj444p (see `ffmpeg -h encoder=mjpeg`). As far as I can tell gray is not acceptable for you, but I am unaware of a format that saves only Y that is not simply just gray.

Comment: PNG supports just Y but only 16 bits for 10 bits. Just as HEVC and AVC, those support even 10 bit perfectly. Both HEVC and AVC can be lossless. Just use .hevc and .h264 files in the end.